# Rails conditional validation throwing undefined method for Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

So, I've been working on an app (Rails 5) and I wanted to verify if the attribute (server) chosen by the user is in the scope I want.

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  validates :nick, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }
  validates :description, length: { maximum: 275 }
  validates :server, presence: true, if: server_exists?

  def server_exists?
    server == "NA"
  end

end
```

When I try to access localhos:3000 I get the following error:

> undefined method `server_exists?' for Player (call 'Player.connection'
>   to establish a connection):Class

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> You can associate the `:if` and `:unless` options with a symbol
>   corresponding to the name of a method that will get called right
>   before validation happens.

Try with `:server_exists?` instead `server_exists?`:

```
validates :server, presence: true, if: :server_exists?
```

Comment: Consider elaboration on *why* this happens, especially the error it self. (Being called directly as a ClassModel, which doesn't exist here)

Comment: Thanks! I will study about why this error happens when ":" is not used.

Comment: You're welcome!, I think you could take a look to the [`ActiveModel::Validations#validates`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/cdb9d7f481a6b299cd53a0f647397da60d806a21/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb#L104) to get a better idea on how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a symbol for the method name:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless

```
validates :server, presence: true, if: :server_exists?
```